# Highcharts text-anchor with HighchartsTable plugin

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts and the HighchartTable plugin.

I have roated my labels 90 degrees and they are showing up correctly.  However the way the text is aligned it is overlapping into the chart itself.

I have figured out a way to fix it and a possible way to fix it but since their API doesn't currently seem to be working (page is just a blank white page).

I am hoping someone on here knows.

There is a `<tspan x="111.6">` where if I change that to `170` it aligns it right where I want to.

There is also a `<text text-anchor="middle" >` where if I change that to `"base"` or `"bottom"` it aligns it correctly.

Is there any way to do this automatically through Highcharts or HighchartsTable?

Here is how I am turning the HTML table into the chart.

```
$('table.highchart').highchartTable();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDkkD/)

Comment: An live demo, please replicate it on the jsfiddle

Comment: @SebastianBochan I added a jsfiddle.

Comment: I advice to cotnact with plugin's authors, because it is not our official plugin.